# Неправильное кодирование символа украинского алфавита

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, кодировка, кириллица

Кодировка БД - koi8r_general_ci, но почему-то когда данные достаються с помощью коннектора символы укр. алфавита заменяються на совершенно другие:
**Олег Іванович** -> **Олег ╤ванович**
Кроме того позже програма делает *INSERT* в БД с использованием полученных раннее данных.

Как возможное решение проблемы был изменнен запрос который вытаскивал ФИО юзера, на такой, который имел конвертацию: 
**CONVERT ( CAST ( users.fio AS BINARY ) USING koi8u ) AS fio**

Вследствии было полученно коректное имя пользователя, но появились ошибки на этапе *INSERT* полученных данных:
**Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x86\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB0...' for column 'fio'**
К сожалению, кодировка ФИО в *utf-8* (**data['fio'].encode('utf-8')**) перед *INSERT* не принесла плодов.

Как правильно сконвертировать полученные данные в koi8_u, чтобы они воспринимались БД? Или же удобнее решить проблему с непонятными иэроглифами?

Comment: `data['fio'].encode('koi8-u')` А ещё лучше поменять кодировку БД на utf-8.

Comment: В случае если SQL-запрос для получения данных будет без конвертации, применение **data['fio'].encode('koi8-u')** в ф-ции, которая выводит ФИО юзера дает следующею ошибку:
**UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2564' in position 15: character maps to <undefined>**